# How to import modules in subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a template directory where my **test.py** file is present.

Path to test.py dir is -
**/user/document/test1/template/test.py**

(I have `__init__.py` as well)

contest of **test.py** is

```
import os

test_dict = {
   'number' : ['1', '2'],
   'values' : ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

What I am trying in other script is

**script.py**

path to script.py is - /**user/document/home/script.py**

```
import os

os.chdir('/user/document/test1/')

exec('from template.test import test_dict')

print(test_dict)
```

And in the same dir I have another file called **run.py**

path to run.py is - **/user/document/home/run.py**

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('python /user/document/home/script.py ',shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
```

Now when I run **run.py** (with pdb debugger) I see the exec from `script.py` is not able to find the template module.

How do I make it right? I want `test_dict` from **test.py** inside **script.py**

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in this post but it seems like you are missing a closing apostrophe in: os.chdir('/user/document/test1/)

Comment: The subprocess is completely independent from the parent; you can't see the internal variables from a C program like the Bash interpreter either, unless it specifically provides an API for querying it. Running Python as a subprocess of itself is often an antipattern, anyway. What you seem to be trying to do is easily achieved by `import`ing the code you want to run into the current script (though it might require some refactoring before you can do that).

Comment: Instead of `os.chdir` add the path to `sys.path`.

Comment: @jlipinski yes there was typo when I am posting this. But I scrips its correct.

Comment: Also, almost certainly avoid `shell=True` here. See [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)